# What was the question about reparations that Josh Lyman almost asked, then didn't?

Tags: the-west-wing

There was a conversation between Josh Lyman and an advocate for [reparations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reparations_for_slavery) to [African Americans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_Americans) that took place in Lyman's office. I think it's the episode mentioned below but not 100% sure now.

I remember Lyman appearing to want to ask a question, starting to, but not following through; something a bit like "But... (pause) never mind." I got the feeling that the question was supposed to be obvious to the viewer, but perhaps the character was conflicted about actually asking it out loud.

**Question:** What was the question about reparations that Josh Lyman almost asked, then didn't?

Likely episode: S1E18 "Six Meetings Before Lunch", per [The_West_Wing_(season_1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_West_Wing_(season_1)):

> Meanwhile, due to an objection by a member of the Senate Judiciary Committee, Josh has a long and vigorous discussion about reparations (of $1.7 trillion) for slavery with a candidate for an appointment to the post of the Assistant Attorney General for Civil Rights.

Comment: Please find the exact dialogue. Far too often questions on this site come down to badly remembered dialogue, which IMHO shouldn't happen considering that it is fairly easy to find the correct scenes online.

Comment: @BCdotWEB there is an answer posted already and it confirms that the episode I'd proposed is correct. I'll now start looking for a script with direction (rather than just a transcript) or a recording. I'm out of my element here and it may take some time.

Comment: I've said nothing about "the wrong episode", I've pointed out that you come here with a barely remembered snippet of dialogue, from which you've constructed a question. If you want clarity about a particular piece of dialogue, at least make the effort to look up its exact words, and review the relevant scene.

Comment: @BCdotWEB vividly remembered, not barely. I made an effort, I was unsuccessful. There's no way to demonstrate a failed search attempt, and there's no need to exaggerate for effect, these are SE comments, not a Tarantino gig :-)

Comment: You claim that you "vividly remember" the scene, yet in your question you say "something a bit like" and none of the three words you posted are in the transcript.

Comment: @BCdotWEB but my memory is nonetheless *vivid*... let's wait until I can get my hands on a recording of the scene and see what it was about it that I picked up on. An ASCII transcript of the dialogue can not convey what a good performance on screen (or even in audio) projects. And we should both continue to try to keep this about the question, not about me, except as it relates to my ability to put information into the question and get it out of the answer. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

From the [transcript](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=18) of that episode, Josh wasn't actually asking about reputations at this point:

> JEFF
> Yes. But the order was rescinded four years later by Andrew Johnson. In the '60s, during the Newark riots, you could hear the looters shouting, "That was my 40 acres, I'll be back for the mule." [drinks coffee]
>
> JOSH
> Catchy.
>
> JEFF
> See, if you guys had just paid up on time...
>
> JOSH
> A lesson well learned. But let's talk about your confirmation.
>
> JEFF
> Absolutely.
>
> JOSH
> And while we're on the subject of the Civil War, let's remember the 600,000 white men who died over the issue of slavery.
>
> JEFF
> Is that why they died?
>
> JOSH
> It's why a lot of them died, Jeff. And there's no other place and time in recorded history where an event like that has occurred. So... let's... leave it at that and move on.
>
> JEFF
> Okay.
>
> JOSH
> Except to say this...
>
> JEFF
> What?
>
> JOSH
> Nothing.
>
> JEFF
> What?
>
> JOSH
> Let's move on.

Josh really had nothing at that point. His personality is such that he had to win, but he realised at that point he really didn't have anything left, so moved on.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the scene, and if so it seems that it wasn't a question not asked, it was the statement unsaid; "Except to say this...". I will try to get access to a recording. I am pretty sure that in the scene there was more of a suggestion that Lyman thought twice and then made a conscious decision not to say what he was preparing to say. This transcript only shows a transcription of the words, without context or cues that might have been in the script, so I don't think we can conclude quite yet that "he really didn't have anything left".

Comment: This script was written by Sorkin who is known not to include much in the way of direction and unspoken thoughts/dialogs in his scripts - if it was in the script, it would have been said - and this was when he was also writing Sports Night, so was even less likely to have written anything more than what was intended to be spoken. I've always viewed this as Josh simply running out of argument - he is not known to be a character that holds back from a retort.

Comment: I share the same impression of the character, which is why I'd found this moment quite odd and it stuck with me all these years. I may be able to round up an old DVD set from a friend (I don't actually watch TV anymore or have access to any services).

Comment: @uhoh - That was my thought. Josh had a zinger (possibly something about white people also suffering from the long-term effects of slavery) and decided that it would be wiser to keep his mouth shut since the goal here isn't to win the argument, but rather to win friends.

Comment: @Valorum I'd thought that Josh's unspoken "zinger" was of the "aren't you better off here, Mr. Senator, because of slavery?" which Josh is smart enough (if taking a nanosecond to think about it, which he did not always do) not to actually utter. I'd never heard of the "white people also suffering from the long-term effects of slavery" as a concept forwarded by any US liberal, seems too far "out of character".